# Riverpod autodipose not working when poping contexts

Tags: flutter, riverpod

When I use:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/addressMapView', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

I expect this to dispose all contexts/route views in the app and the providers, or am I misunderstanding something?

This provider is not being disposed, and I need it to be rebuilt when I navigate to this page.

```
final addressMapService = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose<AddressMapService>((ref) => AddressMapService(read: ref.read));
```

Answer (score 0):

What I found was that if you have a provider being watched anywhere else, riverpod wont dispose it.

So my issue was that I was also watching it in the current screen - it disposed once I removed it.

Makes sense. Great package.